# Simulation running slow, quarter real time

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo with an empty world runs at 0.25x real time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/123/simulation-running-slow,-quarter-real-time/) by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Other symptoms include:

- Not all the cores on the computer are
  working. Testable with: cat/proc/cpuinfo
- The following code has   4 ms intervals

  ```
   #include <sys/time.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   main()
   {
     struct timeval tv;
     struct timeval tv_old;
     gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
     tv_old = tv;
     while(1)
     {
       gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
       if (tv_old.tv_usec != tv.tv_usec)
       {
         printf("%ld %ld\n", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
         tv_old = tv;

         // sleep 1 nano second
         struct timespec nsleep;
         nsleep.tv_sec = 0;
         nsleep.tv_nsec = 1;
         nanosleep(&nsleep, NULL);
       }
     }
   }
  ```

##Solution

- Edit `/etc/default/grub` and remove `acpi=off`
- sudo update-grub
- restart

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

also documented in [issue #178](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/178/nanosleep-on-systems-with-large-clock), and patch to bypass clock when kernel resolution is too large is implemented in [pull request #72](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/72/new-time-nsleep-call-sleep-will-check-to/diff).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-10-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-04**:
Could this issue (or something closely related) cause the time that gazebo sees move faster than  timeit.default_timer (or gettimeofday)?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-11-05**:
Not sure, can you provide some more context on the time inconsistency you're seeing?  Thanks.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-12**:
Will post a new question once I can document it properly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have the same problem too. The real problem is that it is not constant, i.e. it varies over time (the real time factor). Is there a way to set it as 1.0?

---

Originally posted by [Neostek](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48/neostek/) with karma: 21 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-11-06**:
Just for clarification, this thread is just about a linux system configuration problem that causes the linux kernel to behave improperly when nanosleeping.  The default behavior of Gazebo > 1.2 is to throttle to 1.0 realtime. Gazebo may still run slower than real time.